# How to stop timer functions on element

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following jquery code starts a timer on all matched elements

```
$.each($('.product, #auction-div'), function () {
    var deadline = new Date(0);
    deadline.setUTCMilliseconds($(this).find('input[name=startDate]').val());
    initializeClock($(this).find('.clockdiv'), deadline);
});
```

Later on my page receives an update and the update contains the updated countdown time left. I have to call the `initializeClock` function with the current countdown time left as in the next code.

```
        success: function (data) {
            comet = subscribe();
            var auction = data.auction;
            if (auction) {
                var productBox = $('#' + data.auction.uid);
                productBox.find('.timer').html('09');
                productBox.find('.auction-price, #auction-price').html('KSh.' + data.auction.auctionValue);
                audio.play();
                var deadline = new Date(0);
                deadline.setUTCMilliseconds(data.countdown);
                initializeClock(productBox.find('.clockdiv'), deadline);
            }
        },
```

This is the code for initializeClock and other relevant functions

```
//    code for countdown timer
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        if (t < 0) {
            days = hours = minutes = seconds = 0;
        }
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }
    function initializeClock(clock, endtime) {
        var daysSpan = clock.find('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.find('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.find('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.find('.seconds');
        function updateClock() {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
            daysSpan.html(t.days);
            hoursSpan.html(('0' + t.hours).slice(-2));
            minutesSpan.html(('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2));
            secondsSpan.html(('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2));
            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        }
        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
```

Unfortunately this results in multiple clocks initialized on the `clockDiv` with the countdown becoming incrementally chaotic.

I have tried the following methods before initializing the clock subsequently

1. `.clearQueue()`
2. And calling the `.stop()` even though its for animations i had to try`
3. Next I wan't to try removing the parent element containing the clock div and replacing it again to see if this will unbind the bound events.

Meanwhile I hope there's a one-liner elegant solution.

PS I don't have a reference to any variable that I can call `clearInterval(timeinterval);` so let's not dwell on that please.

Comment: Please show us `initializeClock` implementation.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I have added the code. Can we please stop it with the serial down voting people.

Comment: Not my **dv**, thanks for providing the clarification.

Comment: @gurvinder372 The most irritating thing about it is that the DVers came in literary 2 seconds after posting the question, hardly enough time for anyone to have read the question and didn't add any value whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `timer` property to the *element itself* so that you can use it next time.

```
function initializeClock(clock, endtime) {
    var timeinterval = clock.prop( "clockTimer" );
    if ( timeinterval )
    {
        return; //timer already started on this, so no need to create a new one
    }
    //rest of the code

    timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    clock.prop( "clockTimer", timerInterval );
}
```

> How to stop timer functions on element

You can implement a `stop` function

```
function stopTimer( clock )
{
        var timeinterval = clock.prop( "clockTimer" );
        if ( timeinterval )
        {
            clearInterval( timeInterval );
        }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks and God bless.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `initializeClock` doesn't return the timer handle and doesn't store it anywhere that you can access it. So you have two options:

1. If you have access to `initializeClock` (or can tell someone who does have access to it to modify it), modify it so it stores the timer handle on the element in question (perhaps using jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method). Then you can retrieve it and clear the previous interval timer before starting the next.
2. If you don't have access to it, the **very much worse** option than #1 is to remove the element and replace it with a clone (pehaps via jQuery's [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) methods). That way, although the old interval timer still runs (we have no way of stopping it), the element it's updating is no longer in the DOM and isn't showing on the page anymore.

#2 is very much a workaround, not a solution, because over time you'll build up interval timers that are doing work for no good reason.